# How to draw a Huffman tree properly

Tags: huffman-code

I have the following symbols and probabilities and I would like to draw a Huffman tree for them:

```
s = 0.04 || i = 0.1 || n = 0.2 || b = 0.04 || a = 0.3 || d = 0.26 || ~ = 0.06
```

Based on Huffman algorithm, I generated the following tree:

[image]

This was done by:

1. Join `s + i`
2. Join the result of 1 and `n`
3. Join `~ + d`
4. Join `b + a`
5. Join the result of 3 and 4
6. Join the result of 5 and 2

My questions:
is what I have done right or not? If so, is it acceptable that the final probability (result of 6) greater than 1?

Thanks

Comment: 0.34 + 0.66 = 1.0, and the probability will always equal 1, however your approach does not seem like a huffman's one - why `s + i` instead of `s + b` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you have done is not right, and no, the only thing that is acceptable is that the final number must equal the sum of the starting numbers.

The sums do match in your case, since 0.34 + 0.66 = 1, so I don't know why you're asking that. By the way, the numbers do not have to be probabilities, so the sum does not have to be 1. Often the numbers are frequencies, i.e. the count of the number of times that symbol appeared.

As for your tree, you must always join the *two lowest numbers*, be they a leaf or the top of a sub-tree. At the start, that's `s = 0.04` and `b = 0.04`. You didn't do that, so your tree does not represent the application of Huffman's algorithm. Then to that 0.08 you add `~ = 0.06`. And so on.